# boost installation won't install without stating at least one lib?

Tags: boost

I'd like to install just the mpl and preprocessor portions of the library but if I use this command, it tries to build and install all of them:

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries= --prefix=<my lib path>
```

I see that it is trying to because it is executing the compiler.  Using *./b2 -n* also shows the commands being executed.

Does anyone know what is happening?  The default of *--with-libraries=* is supposed to be all according to the help:

```
--with-libraries=list     build only a particular set of libraries,
                          describing using either a comma-separated list of
                          library names or "all"
                          [all]
--without-libraries=list  build all libraries except the ones listed []
```

Empty shouldn't default to all, Empty should mean empty.  Not specifying *--with-libraries=* should default to all.

Also, *--without-libraries=all* doesn't work either.  It's a bit disappointing considering that this library has been around so long.  You'd think that these people would check a simple boundary case like that. :(

Comment: Actually, my question isn't just what's happening, but how do I install just those two?  I'm not going to be using the same compiler as is in my regular work environment.  I expected those two header types just to drop in without muss or fuss.  Only doing this install route as it seems the cleanest and the drop in didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any way except to view all libraries and then specify them all after the --without-libraries= flag.  However, it looks like it actually doesn't do anything, which means, I can just copy the header folder over to the include directory that I desire.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience when upgrading boost, there are some tests run to see if boost is compatible with your system/compiler. In [our] case we needed `filesystem` and `system`, so it was the method we used in case of **boost 1_51_0**. I hope it will help.
Note: We needed static libraries only (.a) that could be compiled with shared libraries (.so). That is why we add `cxxflags=-fPIC`, and then we copy .a files into `lib64` directory.

```
tar xf boost_1_51_0.tar.gz
rm boost_1_51_0.tar.gz
./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=filesystem,system --exec-prefix=$(pwd)
./b2 cxxflags=-fPIC
mkdir lib64
cp $(find . -name '*.a' -print | grep -v stage | grep release ) lib64
cd lib64
# Now you can delete any libraries you don't need.
```

Note also that you can call `./bootstrap.sh --show-libraries` to see all available libraries.

Comment: But I don't need any tests done, except maybe to say if the C++ compiler is compatible with the mpl and preprocessor libraries.  They are only header files, so they shouldn't need any real testing and definitely don't need compiling.  Any failures would be reported at the time I try to compile against them.

So this isn't the answer that I'm looking for. (no hand wave required ;) )

Comment: The boost set itself needs to do test so it can tell if it is in workable condition (with your system and with your compiler.) It is a form of integrity test. There is also much bigger regression test that can be run separately, which you don't need to do. Anyway, I wonder, if you need header files only, maybe simple tar xf is enough?

Comment: That is what I thought.  In fact I had tried to use the --without-libraries with all of the libraries that were stated when I used the --show-libraries.  It stated that there wasn't anything to be done and then told me to point the include path to the directory I was installing from and the linker lib path to a subdirectory of the same.  Nothing was moved to the dirs I specified.  Not impressed.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that it does do some configuring, which I thought it would get from C++ macros.  So, now before I tried to do a drop in, it failed with some error that I looked up and said I needed to install it.  Now that I've installed it, I moved the boost dir to the correct location and it fails probably because it tried to use my default g++ instead of the avr-g++ that I want it to use.  Hrm.

Comment: Oh and what I meant by "Not impressed" was that what is the point of specifying paths if the install isn't going to use them to install to?

Comment: Seems that when I moved it the IDE didn't like it where I put it.  Argh!  What a PITA!